# pandas isin append unhashable type: 'list' error

Tags: python, pandas

I ran out of idea on how to add new items to filter list in pandas.

Example:

```
OldProducts = ProductInfo[ProductInfo['MerchantID'].isin(['A store', 'B store'])]

OldProductsId = list(OldProducts.PID.unique())

OldProductsId2 = ['VayjE7nrDl', 'BYbcAAuV0r', 'hu2y8rYIbN', 'YXELEovcwK']

OldProductsId.append(OldProductsId2)

DetailProductInfo = DetailProductInfo [~DetailProductInfo ['PID'].isin(OldProductsId)]
```

The error is like this:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `append` method will add the item you pass as another *item* in the list. If that *item* happens to be another list then the final element in your list will be the `OldProductsId2` list. Use `extend` instead.

Change `OldProductsId.append(OldProductsId2)` to `OldProductsId.extend(OldProductsId2)`

Answer (score 1):

You've appended OIdProductsId2 to OldProductsId, so now OldProductsId is a list of (presumably) strings plus a list object. So to correct your code change this line:

```
OldProductsId.append(OldProductsId2)
```

To:

```
OldProductsId.extend(OldProductsId2)
```

And the error should disappear.